# Adding button to QGIS toolbar to add new feature into non-geometrc table

Tags: pyqgis, gui

I am working with a non-geometric table in QGIS and I'm trying to streamline the process of adding new entries to this table by creating a custom button in the QGIS toolbar. My goal is for this button to switch the "Addresses" layer to edit mode and open the attribute form for adding a new feature, all without the need for any geometry since it's an attribute-only table.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

def add_address():
    layer_name = "Adressen"
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    if not layer.isEditable():
        layer.startEditing()

    # This is where I'm stuck. 
    # I need to open the attribute form for a new entry in a non-geometric layer.

# Create an action for the toolbar
action = QAction(QIcon(""), "Add Address", iface.mainWindow())
action.triggered.connect(add_address)

# Add the action to the toolbar
iface.addToolBarIcon(action)
```

When I click the button, I want it to open the attribute form for a new record in my "Addresses" table. I understand that iface.actionAddFeature().trigger() won't work for non-geometric layers since it's designed for layers with geometry.

Can you guide me on how to open the attribute form for a new entry in a table without associated geometry?

Comment: `iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()` does trigger the addition of a new "record" to a geometry-less table fine for me.